Galois connection and the map preserves arbitrary meets
On page 162 of Introduction to Lattices and Order, second edition, by Davey and Priestley, 7.34 says that:

Let $P$ and $Q$ be ordered sets and $\varphi:P\to Q$ be a map.
(i) Assume $P$ is a complete lattice. Then $\varphi$ preserves arbitrary joins if and only if $\varphi$ possesses an upper adjoint $\varphi^{\#}$ (that is, $(\varphi,\varphi^{\#})$ is a Galois connection).
(ii) Assume $Q$ is a complete lattice. Then $\varphi$ preserves arbitrary meets if and only if $\varphi$ possesses a lower adjoint $\varphi^{b}$ (that is, $(\varphi^{b},\varphi)$ is a Galois connection).

In (ii), should we still assume that $P$ is a complete lattice? If we want to show that $\varphi$ preserves arbitrary meets, then $P$ must have arbitrary meets. But we don't have that here.

I do think it should be $P$ in both cases.

Thanks! I will check (ii) with the same assumption as (i).

They are formally dual: $P$ is a complete lattice iff $P^\mathrm{op}$ is a complete lattice; $\varphi$ preserves joins iff $\varphi^\mathrm{op} : P^\mathrm{op} \to Q^\mathrm{op}$ preserves meets, and $(\varphi, \varphi^#)$ is an adjunction iff $({\varphi^#}^\mathrm{op}, \varphi^\mathrm{op})$ is.

Thanks for the dual argument!
